# Setting a global #define in XCode

Tags: xcode

Can you please tell me how can I set a global #define in my Xcode project?
I don't want to put #define DEBUG in every .h of my project.

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is generally done in the Xcode project properties. Right-click on the project itself in the project window (the project is the top level of the heirarchy) and choose "get info". This will bring up the project inspector window. In the inspector window, choose the "Build Settings" tab. Now, use the search field to find an entry called "preprocessor macros", and put the string `DEBUG` into that entry.

If you do this only for the "Debug" build configuration (there should be a drop-down menu within the project inspector window), then this `DEBUG` macro will only be #defined when you are actually debugging.

See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/400-Build_Configurations/build_configs.html) for all the dirty details.

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use your project's `.pch` file.  It stand for precompiled header file and it compiled before any other file in your project.

This means if you put a `#define` or an `#import` in the `.pch` file it will be included in every file in your project.

**EDIT**

As I have recently found out, you have to be carful using the `.pch` file.

-- EVERY CHANGE YOU MAKE TO A FILE IN THE `.pch` **EVERY** FILE WILL BE RECOMPILED.--

IF you have a large project this could take some time.